# Write a query to display the names of the department and the staff count in each department, if staff not exist display the count as 0

Tags: oracle

Write a query to display the names of the department and the staff count in each department, if the staff does not exist display the count as 0. Give an alias to staff count as staff_count. Sort the result based on department name.

This is what I tried.

```
select department_name,count(*) as staff_count
from left join staff on department.department_id=staff.staff_id
group by department_name order by department_name;
```

I think there is something missing in my code.

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data, the result you're getting and the result you'd like to get for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write your query as:

```
SELECT
    d.department_name,
    d.department_id,
    COUNT(s.staff_id) AS cnt
FROM department d
LEFT JOIN staff s
    ON d.department_id = s.department_id
GROUP BY
    d.department_name,
    d.department_id
ORDER BY
    d.department_name;
```

You want to join from the `department` out to the `staff` table, to multiply each department record by however many staff it contains.  We count staff values, which handles the case of a given department having no staff.

Note that I assume that `department_id` is the name of the join column in both tables.  If not, then modify the above query accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    d.department_name,
    COUNT(s.staff_id) AS staff_count
FROM department d
LEFT JOIN staff s
    ON d.department_id = s.department_id
GROUP BY
    d.department_name,
    d.department_id
ORDER BY
    d.department_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this in some other approach. Then you can try the below code.

```
1 select d.department_name,count(s.staff_id) as staff_count
2 from department d,staff s
3 where d.department_id=s.department_id(+)
4 group by department_name
5 order by department_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

select department_name,count(student_name) as student_count from department
natural join student
group by department_name
order  by department_name;

Comment: From Review:  Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
    department_name,
    nvl(count(staff_id,0)as staff_count 
from department
inner join staff 
    on department.department_id=staff.department_id
group by department_name
order by department_name
```